# How to create a login function to a specific user

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This app can register 2 main users student and teacher. After registering the users, they can login. If the user is a teacher it will redirect to teacher activity and if it's a student it will redirect to a different activity in the register page. Student and teacher will selected by a checkbox.

this is the code I've tried so far :

```
 String user = username.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();

                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_USER + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.NAME + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD + "=?", new String[]{user,pass});
                if(username.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 ||
                        password.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
                    toast(MainActivity.this,"All fields are required");
                }
                else if (cursor != null){
                    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
                        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TYPE)).equals("Teacher")){
                            view_teacher();
                            toast(MainActivity.this,"Welcome " + username.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
                        }
                        else{
                            view_student();
                            toast(MainActivity.this,"Welcome " + username.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        toast(MainActivity.this,"Username or Password invalid");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    toast(MainActivity.this,"Error Login in");
                }
            }
        });
```

This is how the register function looks like

```
}else if (db.registeruser(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(),teacher.isChecked() ? "Teacher" : (student.isChecked() ? "Student" : "N/A"))){
                    loginScreen();
                    toast(Register.this,"Successfully Registered Please Login");
                }
```

When i tried to execute the login function the app will crash

Comment: post your log or error/crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not post the error log, but I think the error you get is thrown because you do not call and check `cursor.moveToFirst()` before you try to access the row returned by `rawQuery()` so the cursor's position is before the 1st row.
Also move the call to `rawQuery()` inside the `else` block:

```
String user = username.getText().toString().trim();
String pass = password.getText().toString().trim();

if(user.length() == 0 || pass.length() == 0){
    toast(MainActivity.this,"All fields are required");
} else {
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_USER + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.NAME + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD + "=?", new String[]{user,pass});
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TYPE)).equals("Teacher")){
            view_teacher();
        } else {
            view_student();
        }
        toast(MainActivity.this,"Welcome " + username.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
    } else {
        toast(MainActivity.this,"Username or Password invalid");
    }
}
```